My program seems to not be adding any item to a given list
I'm currently learning Python, so my problem is very basic. I have to write a program that takes any natural number by keyboard, verify if that number is a multiple of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9, and create a list with the numbers found. Then I have to display the list, ordered from largest to smallest if there is any possible multiple present.
I wrote this program, however it is not working as I expected, it always prints "None". Can you please explain me why is it happening, where is the error? How can I get it to work without getting too much into advanced stuff yet?
enteredValue=int(input("Enter a natural number."))
possibleMultiples=[]

for num in range(2,10):
    if enteredValue % num == 0:
        possibleMultiples.append(enteredValue)

print(possibleMultiples.reverse())


.reverse() doesn't return a new reversed list; it reverses the actual list and then returns None.

Jon, in addition to John Gordon's comment, I think you want to append num and not enteredValue.

@Carl Trask, I think the OP wants print(possibleMultiples[::-1]), taking advantage of slicing.

5rod, I think you are right.  Good catch.
